# MySQL query to get same column data in two rows

Tags: mysql

I have a database and I am facing issue to getting the data in the format below.

Table is as below

```
+----+---------+----------+
| ID |   ign   |   time   |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 |    NULL | 12:30    |
|  2 |    1    | 12:31    |
|  3 |    NULL | 12:32    |
|  4 |    NULL | 12:33    |
|  5 |    NULL | 12:34    |
|  6 |    0    | 12:35    |
|  3 |    NULL | 12:36    |
|  3 |    NULL | 12:37    |
|  2 |    1    | 12:38    |
|  3 |    NULL | 12:39    |
|  4 |    NULL | 12:40    |
|  5 |    NULL | 12:41    |
|  6 |    0    | 12:42    |
|  3 |    NULL | 12:43    |
|  3 |    NULL | 12:44    |
+----+---------+----------+
```

My Resultant table should be in the below format.

```
Start  | Start Time | Stop |Stop Time
-------+------------+------+-------------
 1     |  12:31     |   0  |     12:35
 1     |  12:38     |   0  |     12:42
```

I am completely new to MySQL and have no idea how this can be achieved.

Comment: Specify MySQL version.

Comment: mysql version 5.7.28-0

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 1 Start, t1.time `Start Time`, 0 Stop, MIN(t2.time) `Stop Time`
FROM src_table t1
JOIN src_table t2 ON t2.time > t1.time AND t2.ign = 0
GROUP BY t1.time
WHERE t1.ign = 1
```

Comment: Thank you. It would be great if you could explain the query. I am quite new to MySQL.

Comment: @nXn Sorry, but SO is not aimed at initial training. If you don't understand a particular point-ask, but to explain everything, and even in detail, here just no one will.